# What happens if I change meta tags after the DOM has materialized?

Tags: javascript, browser, meta-tags

Looking through the A-Frame [source](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/scene/metaTags.js), I spot that the library sets several meta tags with JavaScript.

This should be safe in A-Frame's case: Mozilla recommend that their library is imported as a blocking, synchronously loaded script in the `<head>`, so this work will always happen before we exit `<head>` parsing.

Still, it got me thinking: what happens if one changes meta tags with JavaScript in an async script, or after `DOMContentLoaded`?

Some specific questions:

- is there any guarantee that browsers will respect meta tag mutations?
- are there known issues with getting a browser to recognise meta tag changes after `<head>` parsing / DOM materialisation? Will they still 'do things' to the page?
- are there any other good reasons I shouldn't do this if the meta tags are critical to the job my JavaScript does?

Comment: Which meta tags? What do you hope to achieve by changing them?

Comment: @Quentin Any. I have no intention in mind. I just want to know if this is safe; if it is common; if the behaviour is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any guarantee in the specs that browsers should respect meta tag mutations?

They are DOM elements, like any other.

The specs won't mention anything specific because they aren't special cases.

> are there known issues with getting a browser to recognise meta tag changes after `<head>` parsing / DOM materialisation?

Not from the POV of examining them in the DOM afterwards.